# Visual Studio Android Emulators keep running even after being closed

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator, android-device-monitor

I am using the [Visual Studio Android Emulator](https://beta.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/). Sometimes (I haven't identified when) I close the emulator, run it again etc. and it seems to be creating multiple unclosed instances of the emulator.

[image]

When I examine the Hyper-V Manager I can see that all of them are in Off state (the selected one is the one I ran multiple times):

[image]

Any ideas how to get rid of those shut down devices (other than restarting the machine :) ) Is this normal behavior and I just missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but I think Android Device Monitor shows multiple emulator devices because the IP of the running VM changes and Android debug bridge uses IP to discovers a new virtual devices.

Comment: Thanks for the input but that still wouldn't answer of how to get rid off them. I especially need to shut these instances down as UI tests do not run if there is multiple devices connected.

Comment: Checkout [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2017/03/20/phone-emulator-containers-vms-networking-finally-working/).  The last bit talks about network cleanup.